# OpenCV Rectangle Filled

Tags: python, image, opencv, video

[image]I am trying to fill the rectangle but even after changing the code(chaning thickness to -10) there is no effect. I feel that the global has something to do with this.

I have attached the code below.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from .utils import download_file

initialize = True
net = None
dest_dir = os.path.expanduser('~') + os.path.sep + '.cvlib' + os.path.sep + 'object_detection' + os.path.sep + 'yolo' + os.path.sep + 'yolov3'
classes = None
COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(80, 3))




def draw_bbox(img, bbox, labels, confidence, colors=None, write_conf=False):

    global COLORS
    global classes

    if classes is None:
        classes = populate_class_labels()

    for i, label in enumerate(labels):

        if colors is None:
            color = COLORS[classes.index(label)]            
        else:
            color = colors[classes.index(label)]

        if write_conf:
            label += ' ' + str(format(confidence[i] * 100, '.2f')) + '%'

        cv2.rectangle(img, (bbox[i][0],bbox[i][1]), (bbox[i][2],bbox[i][3]), color,-1)
        cv2.putText(img, label, (bbox[i][0],bbox[i][1]-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)

    return img

def detect_common_objects(image):

    Height, Width = image.shape[:2]
    scale = 0.00392

    global classes
    global dest_dir

    config_file_name = 'yolov3.cfg'
    config_file_abs_path = dest_dir + os.path.sep + config_file_name

    weights_file_name = 'yolov3.weights'
    weights_file_abs_path = dest_dir + os.path.sep + weights_file_name    

    url = 'https://github.com/arunponnusamy/object-detection-opencv/raw/master/yolov3.cfg'

    if not os.path.exists(config_file_abs_path):
        download_file(url=url, file_name=config_file_name, dest_dir=dest_dir)

    url = 'https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights'

    if not os.path.exists(weights_file_abs_path):
        download_file(url=url, file_name=weights_file_name, dest_dir=dest_dir)    

    global initialize
    global net

    if initialize:
        classes = populate_class_labels()
        net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights_file_abs_path, config_file_abs_path)
        initialize = False

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scale, (416,416), (0,0,0), True, crop=False)

    net.setInput(blob)

    outs = net.forward(get_output_layers(net))

    class_ids = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    conf_threshold = 0.5
    nms_threshold = 0.4

    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5 and class_id=='person':
                center_x = int(detection[0] * Width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * Height)
                w = int(detection[2] * Width)
                h = int(detection[3] * Height)
                x = center_x - w / 2
                y = center_y - h / 2
                class_ids.append(class_id)
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])


    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, conf_threshold, nms_threshold)

    bbox = []
    label = []
    conf = []

    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = boxes[i]
        x = box[0]
        y = box[1]
        w = box[2]
        h = box[3]
        if str(classes[class_ids[i]])=='person':
            bbox.append([round(x), round(y), round(x+w), round(y+h)])
            label.append(str(classes[class_ids[i]]))
            conf.append(confidences[i])

    return bbox, label, conf
```

The entire code is the above. It is an object detection program using Yolo and opencv. I have also added few lines in the last line to enable only the person class but it seems to detect all classes. I have also tried to modify the thickness of the rectangles but changing the values had no effect.

Comment: You don't need to declare globals inside a function *unless* you are actually modifying the values; you're not changing `COLORS` so you don't need to declare it as `global`. How are you defining `bbox` and `labels`? Hard to answer your question otherwise...

Comment: bbox and label is defined in the last as fucntion detect_common_objects.

Comment: Please condense your question into a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I understand you left part of the code out to not dump a ton of code here, but both dumping tons of code as well as incomplete code are both unhelpful. Give an actual example, complete with a picture, that has the absolute minimum amount of code to replicate the issue. I.e., load a single image, manually define a single bounding box, and draw it.

Comment: The above is the absolute minimum since the object detection programme needs all the functions above. I have attached a photo.

Comment: No it isn't, as you said the problem is in drawing the boxes on the images. If you can get code to draw pictures on boxes, then that is not your problem and can be eliminated from the question, and your question changes from "my program isn't filling rectangles" to "yolo isn't detecting what I want." Your program obviously does a ton more stuff than just drawing filled rectangles. For e.g. you're filtering stuff based on some confidence threshold, which has absolutely nothing to do with drawing rectangles...

Comment: Apologies. My problem is that despite putting a value of -1 for the thickness, I was unable to get a filled rectangle(as shown above).  I will edit my question. However, my problem is not yolo isnt detecting what I want. It is detecting what I want but I want the rectangles(drawn around the detected object) to be filled.

Answer (score 11):

I have a boundary of rectangles and for filling these rectangles. Put "-1"

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 255), -1)
```

Comment: wrong ..doesnt work ..its filling up the whole doc

Comment: @VikramMurthy there was a mistake in the answer - 3rd parameter should be (x2, y2), not (w, h)

Answer (score 9):

You just have to change -10 with -1. after change your code will look like

```
def draw_bbox(img, bbox, labels, confidence, colors=None, write_conf=False):

    global COLORS
    global classes

    if classes is None:
        classes = populate_class_labels()

    for i, label in enumerate(labels):

        if colors is None:
            color = COLORS[classes.index(label)]            
        else:
            color = colors[classes.index(label)]

        if write_conf:
            label += ' ' + str(format(confidence[i] * 100, '.2f')) + '%'

        cv2.rectangle(img, (bbox[i][0],bbox[i][1]), (bbox[i][2],bbox[i][3]), color,-1)
        cv2.putText(img, label, (bbox[i][0],bbox[i][1]-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)

    return img
```

Comment: I have made the following changes but it has no effect.

Comment: Whats the error because i tried in my local and was able to get filled rectangle.

Comment: really? The rectangle is not getting filled.

Comment: haha, dude, you change your question...what is the problem are you facing??

Comment: My problem is that the rectangle is not getting filled. I changed my question because I thought the other part of my code might be affecting my cv2.rectangle function.

Comment: okay, but i think this line of code should do. since, this line is responsible for filling the rectange`cv2.rectangle(img, (bbox[i][0],bbox[i][1]), (bbox[i][2],bbox[i][3]), color,-1)` and if you change -1 with positive non zero integer it will be the border size of the drawn rectangle.

Comment: Yes, I know that but nothing is getting changed on my result.

Comment: I also tried to change the color of the text by entering (0,0,0) instead of color but it has no effect(This is not the main issue but still Im trying to state that even after changing my programme there seems to be no effect).

Comment: then i doubt you were using this function to draw the rectangle on the image.

Comment: dude, it you try to make simple sudo program to draw the rectangle on any image then draw rectangle function will work. Try to post whole code if possible then it would be easy to debug

Answer (score 1):

I was indeed making a dumb mistake. I was changing the object/detection.py file in my Github Folder. However, when I saw this everything made sense.

```
File "/Users/dukeglacia/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvlib/object_detection.py"
```

I was in fact changing the wrong file(exactly the same originally though).

Comment: Thanks for admitting this.  It completes the story :D